# Yii2 is sending GET request on smartphones but POST request on computers

Tags: php, post, methods, yii2, screen

I'm trying to send a POST request to logout action in Yii2. Here is my code:

```
<?= Html::a(' Logout', Url::to(['/site/logout']),[
                                'class'=>['icon', 'icon fa-times'],
                                'title'=>'Logout',
                                'data-method'=>'post',
                            ]) ?>
```

I already tried this too, and didn't work:

```
<?= Html::a(' Logout', Url::to(['/site/logout']),[
                                'class'=>['icon', 'icon fa-times'],
                                'title'=>'Logout',
                                'data' => [
                                     'method' => 'post',
                                ],
                            ]) ?>
```

Both works perfect only on Computers, or devices with big screens, but if I open the page and try to logout on any smartphone, it does not work, and it gives me a:

**Method Not Allowed (#405). This URL can only handle the following request methods: POST.**

I try in my computer and works, but if I use the developer options on Firefox or Chrome and resize de screen simulating a phone, it does not works, and I noticed it send a GET request, but if I restore the original size of screen, it works again and send a POST request. I have spents hours trying to solve it, but I don't know what is the problem, how is it possible that the method (GET or POST) depends of the screen size?

PS: I have already added the YiiAsset to the AppAsset.php, but still get the error.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you have JavaScript enabled on the mobile? Link with `data-method="post"` will work as POST only with JS enabled.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Comment: "developer options on Firefox or Chrome and resize de screen simulating a phone" - can you clarify a bit what options you use there? Based on quick look I wasn't able to find such options from developer tools.